# Counting the number of stars in a diamond pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I am working on a program that prints a diamond shaped pattern in Python.

Below is my code:

```
a=int(input("Enter the minimum number of stars:"))
b=int(input("Enter the maximum number of stars:"))

rows=(b-a+1)
for i in range(rows):
    print(' '*(rows-i-1)+'* '*(i+a))
for j in range(rows-2,-1,-1):
    print(' '*(rows-j-1)+'* '*(j+a))
```

Below is a screenshot of the output of the executed code:

[image: screenshot]

I need to print the total number of stars in my pattern. However, the count() is not working in this case.

Can you suggest an alternative way for this?

Comment: I don't see `count()` anywhere in your code. Could you be more specific about how you're using it and what the error is?

Comment: *How* is `.count()` not working for you? Note that the number of stars could [simply be calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, 
Isn't .count() applicable to lists only?

Comment: @AishwaryaRai: [no, it is not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your code already counts how many stars it needs to print in each `for` loop:

```
for i in range(rows):
    print(' '*(rows-i-1)+'* '*(i+a))
    #                          ^^^  number of stars on this line
for j in range(rows-2,-1,-1):
    print(' '*(rows-j-1)+'* '*(j+a))
    #                          ^^^  number of stars on this line
```

so you could just sum those numbers as you print.

But you really don't need to count or sum anything, you can instead *calculate*.

You are constructing triangles, so you can use the [triangle number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) to calculate the number of stars that go into a triangle. For a triangle made up of `n` rows, the number of stars required is:

```
n x (n + 1)
-----------
    2
```

Every time you set the minimum number of stars, `a`, to 1, you have two whole triangles: one with `b` rows, and one with `b - 1` rows; e.g. for the sample image, where `b` is set to 5, there are 5 rows in the top triangle:

```
1.     *
2.    * *
3.   * * *
4.  * * * *
5. * * * * *
```

and 4 more in the bottom:

```
4.  * * * *
3.   * * *
2.    * *
1.     *
```

When `a` is greater than one, you are basically leaving two smaller triangles, both of height `a - 1`. Say `a = 3`, you are leaving out the first and last two rows:

```
1.     .       # not printed
2.    . .      # not printed
3.   * * *
4.  * * * *
5. * * * * *
4.  * * * *
3.   * * *
2.    . .      # not printed
1.     .       # not printed
```

so you can calculate the number of stars needed the triangle number of `b`, plus the triangle number of `b - 1`, subtracting the triangle number of `a - 1`, twice.

This is the code to do the calculation:

```
def triangle_number(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2

total_stars = triangle_number(b) + triangle_number(b - 1) - (2 * triangle_number(a - 1))
```

For the example in the image, `a = 1` and `b = 5`, the above calculates the number of stars in a triangle with 5 rows (`b`), in a triangle with 4 rows (`b - 1`, the inverted triangle), and subtracts the stars you'd have to remove if `a` is greater than 1 (so `0` here):

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 5
>>> triangle_number(5)
15
>>> triangle_number(4)
10
>>> triangle_number(0)
0
>>> triangle_number(b) + triangle_number(b - 1) - (2 * triangle_number(a - 1))
25
```

For `a = 5` and `b = 9`, the output looks like this:

```
    * * * * *
   * * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
   * * * * * *
    * * * * *
```

and the formula correctly tells you how many stars that had to print:

```
>>> a, b = 5, 9
>>> triangle_number(b) + triangle_number(b - 1) - (2 * triangle_number(a - 1))
61
>>> """
...     * * * * *
...    * * * * * *
...   * * * * * * *
...  * * * * * * * *
... * * * * * * * * *
...  * * * * * * * *
...   * * * * * * *
...    * * * * * *
...     * * * * *
... """.count('*')
61
```

You can further simplify the formulas here by summing the triangle formulas for `b`; substituting the `b` and `b - 1` into the formulas; you are basically creating a *square* of size `b` when `a` is 1:

```
(b * (b + 1) // 2) + (b - 1) * b // 2) ==
(b * (b + 1)) + ((b - 1) * b) // 2 ==
(b * (b + b)) // 2 ==
(b * 2 * b) // 2 ==
b * b
```

Doing the same with the `a - 1` triangles:

```
2 * ((a - 1) * a // 2) ==
(a - 1) * a
```

so the simplified calculation then is:

```
total_stars = b * b - (a - 1) * a
```

and this too produces the correct values:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 5
>>> b * b - (a - 1) * a
25
>>> a, b = 5, 9
>>> b * b - (a - 1) * a
61
```

Comment: The formula can be simplified even more: `b * b - a * (a - 1)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks for the detailed explanation. But I want Python to automatically calculate the total number of stars in the pattern without creating new functions.

Comment: @CristiFati: I was actually working on that simplification before I saw your comment. :-D I don't have that many opportunities to practice basic math these days, strangely enough.

Comment: @AishwaryaRai: How is `b * b - (a - 1) * a` a new function?

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely want to use the `.count` method you have to modify a little your code, but it's easy...

```
>>> a, b = 4, 7    
>>> rows = '\n'.join(' '*abs(i)+'* '*(b-abs(i)) for i in range(a-b, b-a+1))
>>> print(rows)
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
  * * * * * 
   * * * * 
>>> rows.count('*')
37
```

To understand how it works you can try this snippet

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 7
>>> [b-abs(i) for i in range(a-b, b-a+1)]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

However, as I wrote quite a long time ago, I think that the simplest proposition is simply to *count* how many star you're going to print each time and add that to a total counter, like this

```
a=int(input("Enter the minimum number of stars:"))
b=int(input("Enter the maximum number of stars:"))

n_stars = 0
rows=(b-a+1)
for i in range(rows):
    print(' '*(rows-i-1)+'* '*(i+a))
    n_stars += i+a
for j in range(rows-2,-1,-1):
    print(' '*(rows-j-1)+'* '*(j+a))
    n_stars += j+a
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer *n<sub>*</sub> = b² - a² + a* has been algebraically derived [in  this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273257/2749397), here I'd like to show a pictorial derivation of the same result

[image]